# How to create an external login page (SPA) for keycloak

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am currently trying to evaluate a way to create a custom login page, that is not hosted by Keycloak. I am aware that's possible to create themes for the login, but that is not what I want.

We are currently migration from AWS Cognito to Keycloak. With Cognito there are two ways to log in: a hosted (by Cognito) login page or by creating your own login. We did the latter. Our single page application used AWS javascript libs to log in a user. The implementation was able to react to so-called challenges (depending on the flow), i.e. set up MFA device, enter MFA code, password reset ...

With Keycloak, there doesn't seem to be a way to create such an external login application. All you can to is either create your own theme or create a token via REST. However, this means that you already have a username, password, and possibly an MFA token. There is no way to implement a login flow, because after the user entered the username and password, it depends on the current user status, whether he / she has to set a new password, or has to set up a MFA device or accept terms and conditions or something else.

Is the only way to create your own login page by creating a theme? Is there really no way to log in a user with an external SPA?

We already tried to use the following REST endpoint

```
/realms/{REALM_NAME}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
```

but only HTML will be returned (the hosted login page). We weren't able to receive JSON.

Comment: https://www.keycloakify.dev/

Comment: I'm going to add that what you're asking to do can be considered regressive in a security standpoint:  When users give their username and password to a system that is NOT the keycloak URL they have to trust that system in addition to keycloak.  Unnecessarily adding systems that must be trusted is willfully increasing an attack surface.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I can't see the security issue here. The user isn't aware of Keycloak. There is only a login page, i.e. my-domain.com/login. The user trusts that login page, because it's my-domain.com. Keycloak isn't used as a "real" OIDC server here. We want to use Keycloak as a service to manage our users, the login flow and the login process. It's not a system used by third-party apps.

Comment: See my answer to this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77652444/how-can-i-use-keycloak-login-inside-a-react-native-app-without-redirecting-the/77681746#77681746